# Local infix operator definition in Haskell

Tags: haskell

In this Haskell program, `@@` is an infix operator that I want to define only locally within the body of function `f`.  (Naturally enough, my actual program is more complicated than this, and there is a good reason to use infix notation.)

```
infixl 5 @@

(@@) = undefined

f x = x @@ 5 where x @@ y = (x+1) * (y+1)

main = print (f 7)
```

However, unless I also make the global definition, written here as `(@@) = undefined`, GHC complains that 'The fixity signature for `@@` lacks an accompanying binding.'  Is there any way of getting round this without a global definition of the operator symbol?

Comment: Is your `infixl 5 @@` actually being applied to the local `(@@)`? Because that ought to be a bug I would think

Comment: looks like it isn't

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just putting the fixity declaration in the `where` clause seems to work fine:

```
f x = x @@ 5 where
    infixl 5 @@
    x @@ y = (x+1) * (y+1)
```

Comment: I was just about to post this. According to the Haskell 2010 Report, it's 100% legal to put fixity declarations in a where-block. Surprising, but true.

Comment: Ooh, I didn't think of that!

Comment: ... and I suppose I didn't think of it because as a compiler writer, I wouldn't fancy implementing that, or trying to do it and generate reasonable error messages when it went wrong.  Of course it can be done, but it's a job for someone with more youthful enthusiasm than I possess.